# How can I put a decimal point in UNIX live count as stardate

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I'm not overly familiar with javascript, but I've played around with enough to get this far with a script I found on [this site](http://mechiwiki.com/techmed/php/javascript-live-unix-timestamp).

```
<script>
function updateClock ( ) {
var sd = Math.round(new Date().getTime() * 0.0000067322371075102 );
document.getElementById("stardate").firstChild.nodeValue = sd;
}
</script>
<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">
<span id="stardate">&nbsp;</span>
</body>
```

The output is a number that is very close to the stardate calculation used currently in Star Trek Online. However, that number should have the decimal point move left 2 places. Adding and removing zeros in my equation will shorten or extend my count, but I need a decimal, and I'm completely unaware how I can get this to happen.

Does anyone have an idea for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
var sd = ...
var dotted = (sd+"").replace(/..$/,'.$&');
```

Or:

```
var sd = ...
var dotted = (sd/100).toFixed(2);
```

Some advice:

1. It's not a good idea to mix JavaScript in your HTML; instead of putting JavaScript in HTML attributes programmatically attach your handlers. For example:

   ```
   <!-- in the <head> -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener('load',function(){
       // this code will run once the page has loaded
     },false);
   </script>

   <!-- or alternatively right before </body> put -->

   <script type="text/javascript">
     // this code will run once all elements have been created
   </script>
   ```
2. `setInterval` can take a function value as a reference. Instead of writing:

   ```
   // this creates a new anonymous function that invokes foo()
   // similar to using  new Function("foo()")
   setInterval("foo()",1000);
   ```

   ...better to do this:

   ```
   setInterval(foo,1000); // Functionally equivalent, less typing
   ```

Comment: @lopac1029 Yes. You calculuate `sd` in update clock. Then massage the value afterwards and do with it what you will.

Comment: Got it. Since I'm not super familiar with js, it took some messing around with it. but now I have a stardate clock that will update. Thank you, good sir.